# How to implement blur effect may affect content layered behind the view

Tags: ios, video, uiblureffect

I want to add a blur to video when it is playing online without `UIBlurEffect` of 
system. because it can't adjust the level of blur.do you have some good ideals guys.
or one effect may affect content layered behind the view